# Buttons in MainActivity layout don't show with fragment layout

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have buttons in MainActivity layout and when I start a fragment I want to see this buttons with fragment elements, but I see only fragment elements. What I am doing wrong?

MainAcivity layout

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
        android:id="@+id/send_button"
        android:text="SEND"
        android:background="@color/circleBackground"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:text="SAVE"
        android:id="@+id/save_button"
        android:background="@color/circleBackground"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
        android:background="@color/circleBackground"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:text="+"
        android:id="@+id/post_button"
        android:background="@color/circleBackground"/>

</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Fragment layout (fragment_list)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="@color/mainBackground">

<ListView android:id="@+id/product_listview"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_below="@+id/linear_layout"
          android:dividerHeight="1dp"
          android:divider="@color/circleBackground"
          android:fastScrollEnabled="true">
</ListView>
```

At the current moment I see only Listview when the application is loaded.
In fragment:

```
   @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container,false);
}
```

Comment: are you replacing id=container content for fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in your `FrameLayout`

```
android:layout_below="@+id/linear_layout"
```

Answer (score 0):

You must define that `FrameLayout` must be below to the `LinearLayout`.

```
android:layout_below="@+id/linear_layout"
```

**Full layout**

```
    <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
            android:id="@+id/send_button"
            android:text="SEND"
            android:background="@color/circleBackground"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:text="SAVE"
            android:id="@+id/save_button"
            android:background="@color/circleBackground"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
            android:background="@color/circleBackground"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:text="+"
            android:id="@+id/post_button"
            android:background="@color/circleBackground"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linear_layout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If it helps I am happy about that :)

Answer (score 0):

Your parent layout in the main activity is Relative Layout, and since you haven't set any "relativity" between the linear_layout item and the container, the container is shown above the linear_layout so you can't see it. 
Just define some relation, like putting the container below the linear_layout.

Comment: Thank you! I added layout_below